# Book about children with weaving as special power

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago, I remember reading a book about some kind of fantasy world, with a war. The main characters were a couple of children and their mother, and they had some kind of special power that involved weaving some kind of clothing.

I also distinctly remember them having some kind of wooden statues of gods in their home, and at some point I believe it was revealed that

> they themselves were offspring of those gods.

I read the book in english about 10 years ago, but it already seemed pretty old by then. The main bad guy had a relatively weird name. There was also some kind of pretty important river, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Can you be more precise about when you read this book? “A long time ago” is not very helpful; please try to give an (approximate) date range. Do you have any idea how old it was then? How long was it? Was it just a short story, or great novel? Did you read it in a hardcover or paperback? Do you remember anything about the cover? Was it in English? What country were you in when you read it? Male or female author? Every detail can help! See also [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.

Comment: Do you remember what they were weaving? My first thought was the [Dragon Prince and Dragon Star trilogies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Prince_and_Dragon_Star_trilogies) by Melanie Rawn. The magic users in that universe wove sun/moon/star light to cast spells. I don't remember much else about the series, as I read it 10-15 years ago myself.

Comment: @Ellesedil, that's not it, I think they were weaving a piece of clothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The Spellcoats*, by Diana Wynne Jones.The bad guy is called Kankredin. Wikipedia gives [a full synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spellcoats), but it's too long to paste here.

> The third book in the epic fantasy-adventure series from 'the Godmother of Fantasy', Diana Wynne Jones. Now back in print! For centuries, Dalemark has been a land divided by the warring earldoms of the North and South. Now, with the help of the Undying, the mysterious gods of Dalemark, four extraordinary young people must join forces to reunify their beloved land. Orphaned by war, Tanaqui and her 4 siblings are left alone to fend for themselves. When the people in their village turn against them, they abandon their home to begin a treacherous journey downriver towards the sea. As they draw ever closer, the siblings realise that the land is in the grip of a dark power, wielded by the evil mage Kankredin - and that it is their destiny to defeat him.

Comment: You're right, that was it! I've been wondering what it was called for so long...